# Ignore/Remove null, undefined and empty values in array count - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

**Expected Input:**

```
var arr = [null, 7, 9, undefined, 5, , 0, 8, 2, 1]
console.log(arr.length);
```

**Expected Output:**

Length: 7

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way using [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), it will filter out `null` and `undefined` but will keep `0`.

```js
var array = [null, 7, 9, undefined, 5, , 0, 8, 2, 1];
console.log(array.filter(n=> n == 0 || n ).length)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method and [`Number.isFinite`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isFinite) to get only numbers from array and ignore all *falsy* values except `0` like this:

```js
var arr = [null, 7, 9, undefined, 5, , 0, 8, 2, 1]
arr = arr.filter(Number.isFinite);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate the items and check the value for counting.

```js
var array = [null, 7, 9, undefined, 5, , 0, 8, 2, 1],
    length = 0;

for (let value of array) if (value !== null && value !== undefined) length++;

console.log(length);
```